# How to get proper Json response from a postgresql in spring boot?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I am quite new to spring boot! Pardon my English!! I am stuck somewhere really bad at getting Json response from a legacy postgresql database in spring-boot! 
I have already created a model for Interview. I am receiving Response in a following way such that there are no key:value pairs and there is only values i am receiving!

```
[
    [
        4499,
        "A",
        "Aarti",
        null,
        "Mayuri",
        "Das"
    ],
    [
        10113,
        "A.F.Abdel",
        "Rahman",
        null,
        "Aashi",
        "Jain"
    ],
    [
        969,
        "AADISH",
        "SHAH",
        null,
        "Barkha",
        "Motwani"
    ],
    [
        6992,
        "AADITYA",
        "CHAUHAN",
        null,
        "Mayuri",
        "Das"
    ],
```

I have tried passing direct arguments in function so that it directly fetches the data but Typecasting error is encountered because of postgres default id nature is int and here it is taking integer.

Interview Repository

```
package com.example1.demo.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example1.demo.model.Interview;



@Repository
public interface InterviewRepository extends JpaRepository<Interview, Long> {

    @Query("select a.firstName, a.lastName, i.title from User as a inner join Interview as i on a.id=i.supervisorId inner join MarketingSub as m on i.submissionId=m.id where m.consultantId=91")
    public List<?> findByInterviews();
}
```

I am getting the following error upon passing interview in place of '?'

```
Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object[]] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query com.example1.demo.model.Interview] for value '{Ritwek, Swetank, in-person :: Fri :: 01/01/2016 :: 00:00 CST :: Test Ravi :: testlevel1 :: 1231231231 :: Sagar Khangan}'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query com.example1.demo.model.Interview]",
```

Interview Controller

```
package com.example1.demo.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


import com.example1.demo.repository.InterviewRepository;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class InterviewController {

    @Autowired
    private InterviewRepository interviewRepository;

    @GetMapping("/interview")
    public List<?> getInterviews() {
        return interviewRepository.findByInterviews();
    }
}
```

POM.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I am expecting a proper Json response Wrapped inside a dictionary and in key value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

for multiple tables,create a class `ASimpleUserInterview` with 2 field(User,Interview)

```
package com.example1.demo.model;

import com.example1.demo.model.Interview;
import com.example1.demo.model.User;


public class ASimpleUserInterview{
    private User user;
    private Interview interview;

    public ASimpleUserInterview(){}

    public ASimpleUserInterview(User user, Interview  interview){
        this.user = user;
        this.interview = interview;
    }
    //getter and setter

}
```

then

```
package com.example1.demo.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example1.demo.model.Interview;
import com.example1.demo.model.ASimpleUserInterview;



@Repository
public interface InterviewRepository extends JpaRepository<Interview, Long> {

    @Query("select new com.example1.demo.model.ASimpleUserInterview(a,i) from User as a inner join Interview as i on a.id=i.supervisorId inner join MarketingSub as m on i.submissionId=m.id where m.consultantId=91")
    public List<ASimpleUserInterview> findByInterviews();
}
```

What I wrote on the browser may be wrong.

Comment: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object[]] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query com.example1.demo.model.Interview] for value '{Ritwek, Swetank, in-person :: Fri :: 01/01/2016 :: 00:00 CST :: Test Ravi :: testlevel1 :: 1231231231 :: Sagar Khangan}'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query com.example1.demo.model.Interview]",

Comment: `com.example1.demo.model.Interview` should be an entity class,Please check if it is decorated by `@Entity`、`@Table`、`@Id`、`@Column`

Comment: I have already included this one "com.example1.demo.model.Interview should be an entity class,Please check if it is decorated by @Entity、@Table、@Id、@Column"

Comment: The reason for returning the array is that spring got a `List<Object[]>` instead of an object with a key-value pair.You can try to split it into two queries too.